# GPT2Simple having issues running

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpt-2

I am trying to run this GPT2Simple sample but I am getting errors

```
Original stack trace for 'model/MatMul':
  File "c:/Users/Jerome Ariola/Desktop/Machine Learning Projects/gpt test.py", line 32, in <module>
    steps=1)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\gpt_2_simple\gpt_2.py", line 198, in finetune
    output = model.model(hparams=hparams, X=context, gpus=gpus)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\gpt_2_simple\src\model.py", line 212, in model
    logits = tf.matmul(h_flat, wte, transpose_b=True)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\dispatch.py", line 180, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\math_ops.py", line 2754, in matmul
    a, b, transpose_a=transpose_a, transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py", line 6136, in mat_mul
    name=name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 794, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 3357, in create_op
    attrs, op_def, compute_device)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 3426, in _create_op_internal
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 1748, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()
```

This is the code, taken from https://github.com/minimaxir/gpt-2-simple

I also downgraded from Tensorflow 2.0 to Tensorflow 1.15 because there was an issue with `tf.contrib` or something

```
# https://github.com/minimaxir/gpt-2-simple

import gpt_2_simple as gpt2
import os
import requests

model_name = "124M"
if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join("models", model_name)):
    print(f"Downloading {model_name} model...")
    gpt2.download_gpt2(model_name=model_name)   # model is saved into current directory under /models/124M/

file_name = "shakespeare.txt"

if not os.path.isfile(file_name):
    url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/karpathy/char-rnn/master/data/tinyshakespeare/input.txt"
    data = requests.get(url)
    
    with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
        f.write(data.text)


sess = gpt2.start_tf_sess()
gpt2.finetune(sess,
              file_name,
              model_name=model_name,
              steps=1)

gpt2.generate(sess)
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: I downgraded yet again, initially from tf2.0 to tf1.15 and now to tf1.14. Still same errors.

Here's the complete error I'm getting (or at least where the allocator stops)

```
Limit:                  6696213545
InUse:                  6693793536
MaxInUse:               6693795584
NumAllocs:                    2032
MaxAllocSize:            268435456

2021-03-19 01:21:53.793259: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:319] ***x************************************************************************************************
2021-03-19 01:21:53.798596: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1502] OP_REQUIRES failed at cwise_ops_common.cc:70 : Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[1,12,1024,1024] and type bool on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1356, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1341, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1429, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[1,1024,3072] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
         [[{{node model/h11/mlp/Pow}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Jerome Ariola/Desktop/Desktop 2021/Machine Learning Projects/Drake bot/gpt test.py", line 32, in <module>
    steps=1)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\gpt_2_simple\gpt_2.py", line 337, in finetune
    opt_compute, feed_dict={context: sample_batch()})
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 950, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1173, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1350, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1370, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[1,1024,3072] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
         [[node model/h11/mlp/Pow (defined at C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\gpt_2_simple\src\model.py:56) ]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.


Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node model/h11/mlp/Pow:
 model/h11/mlp/c_fc/Reshape_2 (defined at C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\gpt_2_simple\src\model.py:85)

Original stack trace for 'model/h11/mlp/Pow':
  File "c:/Users/Jerome Ariola/Desktop/Desktop 2021/Machine Learning Projects/Drake bot/gpt test.py", line 32, in <module>
    steps=1)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\gpt_2_simple\gpt_2.py", line 198, in finetune
    output = model.model(hparams=hparams, X=context, gpus=gpus)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\gpt_2_simple\src\model.py", line 197, in model
    h, present = block(h, 'h%d' % layer, past=past, hparams=hparams)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\gpt_2_simple\src\model.py", line 158, in block
    m = mlp(norm(x, 'ln_2'), 'mlp', nx*4, hparams=hparams)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\gpt_2_simple\src\model.py", line 148, in mlp
    h = gelu(conv1d(x, 'c_fc', n_state))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\gpt_2_simple\src\model.py", line 56, in gelu
    return 0.5*x*(1+tf.tanh(np.sqrt(2/np.pi)*(x+0.044715*tf.pow(x, 3))))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py", line 180, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py", line 450, in pow
    return gen_math_ops._pow(x, y, name=name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py", line 7382, in _pow
    "Pow", x=x, y=y, name=name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 788, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3616, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2005, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

PS C:\Users\Jerome Ariola\Desktop\Desktop 2021\Machine Learning Projects>
```

Comment: After looking through the source Github, I might be getting OOM (out of memory) because this model was trained on T4 GPUs, which are beefier than my 1070...